# Displaying a single monthly custom post in a sidebar which automatically changes when the current month changes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a single custom post type on a page, the total number of this particular custom post type is 12 (number of months in a year) and they are gardening tips which give the web site viewer information relevant to the month in which they are viewing the page.

I want to show a post that is relevant only for that current month which would be automatically changed without any interaction by the administrator of the site at midnight on the date that the month changes. There are php functions like date_timestamp_get — which gets the Unix timestamp, I'm unsure how to use that to change the query_posts function if it can accept parameters like that?

The code I'm currently using is as follows which displays the single most recently posted single post, here is the link to the page http://www.chorltonnursery.com/wordpress/gardening-tips/

```
<h3>Gardening Tips</h3>
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1"); the_post(); ?>
<h4>Jobs to do in your garden this month</h4>
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=garden_tips&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php the_content('continue reading'); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn">Gardening Tips</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

My hunch is that some php code could solve this challenge? If anyone knows how to do this in wordpress I would be really made up!

Answer (score 0):

You need a grouping post by month, look at this [EXAMPLE](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/group-posts-by-month)

Or in wp_query add month:

```
query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=13&monthnum=' . date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
```

Look at [WP function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Comment: <?php $monthnum = date('n');
    query_posts('monthnum=$monthnum');?>
    <?php $posts = get_posts('post_type=garden_tips&showposts=1&numberposts=1&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php  global $more;
    $more = 0; the_content("Continue Reading"); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>